# Set up https access to nginx docker container

Tags: docker, nginx, https

I want to be able to access an nginx docker container via the https at https://192.168.99.100. By now I have done the following:

`Dockerfile`:

```
FROM nginx

COPY certs/nginx-selfsigned.crt /etc/ssl/certs/
COPY certs/nginx-selfsigned.key /etc/ssl/private/

COPY default-ssl.conf /etc/nginx/sites-available/default

EXPOSE 443
```

I have the correspondent certificate files in folder `certs`.

The `default-ssl.conf`:

```
server {
    listen       80;
    listen       443 ssl;
    server_name  localhost;
    ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/certs/nginx-selfsigned.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/private/nginx-selfsigned.key;
    location / {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
        index  index.html index.htm;
    }
    error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
    }
}
```

`docker-compose.yaml`

```
version: '3'

services:
  nginx:
    image: mynamespace/nginx_pma
    container_name: nginx_pma
    build:
      context: .
    ports: 
      - 443:443
      - 80:80
```

So, when I run this, I am able to access: 192.168.99.100 which shows NGINX welcome page, but I am unable to make it work on https://192.168.99.100.

The host is Windows 7 with docker toolbox.

Any sugestions?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The reason for your error is because your copying the nginx SSL configuration to a folder nginx does not load by default.
After changing this line in the Dockerfile -
`COPY default-ssl.conf /etc/nginx/sites-available/default`
To this -
`COPY default-ssl.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default-ssl.conf`
I'm able to reach Nginx with https.

Comment: Works! Great! Thanks a lot for your help!